# Don't remove a folder until all files in the folder is older than 24 hours

Tags: windows, vbscript

I'm having a problem with my vsb file. I'm trying to create a script that deletes all files and folders that are older than 24 hours, but it should NOT delete a directory until all the files in it are older than 24 hours. The problem with my script is that it removes all directories even if there are files in it that are younger than 24 hours. I can't really find a solution to my problem, I have searched on google and nothing helped.
This is my script :

```
    Const strPath = "D:\shared\temp"
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Call Search (strPath)
Sub Search(str)
 Dim objFolder, objSubFolder, objFile
 Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(str)
 For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
  If objFile.DateCreated < (Now() - 1) Then
   objFile.Delete(True)
  End If
 Next
 For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.Subfolders 
  Flag = ""
  If objSubFolder.DateCreated < (Now() - 1) Then
   For Each Thing in objSubFolder
    If thing.DateCreated > Now() - 1 then Flag="yes"
   Next
   If Flag = "yes" then objSubFolder.Delete(True)
  End If
 Next
End Sub
```

If anyone here knows what I can change in my script to make it work i would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only delete files older than a indicated limit, and folders should only be deleted if all the files inside match the previous condition, first remove the matching files and then remove folders only if they are empty.

```vbs
Option Explicit

Dim strPath
    strPath = "d:\shared\temp"

    Call removeOldFiles( strPath, DateAdd("h", -24, Now()), False )

Sub removeOldFiles( ByVal currentFolder, timeLimit, deleteFolder )
    ' Retrieve a reference to currentFolder if it is not a FSO.Folder
    If TypeName( currentFolder ) <> "Folder" Then 
        With WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            If .FolderExists( currentFolder ) Then 
                Set currentFolder = .GetFolder( currentFolder )
            Else 
                Exit Sub
            End If 
        End With
    End If

    ' Remove files older than timeLimit
    Dim oFile    
    For Each oFile In currentFolder.Files 
        If oFile.DateCreated < timeLimit Then 
            Call oFile.Delete( True )
        End If
    Next 

    ' Recursive call to clean each subfolder
    Dim oSubFolder    
    For Each oSubFolder In currentFolder.Subfolders
        Call removeOldFiles( oSubFolder, timeLimit, True )
    Next 

    ' If the folder is old enough and it is empty, remove it
    If  currentFolder.DateCreated < timeLimit _ 
        And currentFolder.Files.Count = 0 _ 
        And currentFolder.SubFolders.Count = 0 _ 
        And deleteFolder _ 
    Then 
        Call currentFolder.Delete( True )
    End If
End Sub
```

If you need to keep all files/folders until everything is older and then remove all, then you will need to first check everyting

```vbs
Option Explicit

Dim strPath
    strPath = "d:\shared\temp"

    Call removeOldFolder( strPath, DateAdd("h", -24, Now()) )

Sub removeOldFolder( ByVal currentFolder, timeLimit )
    If recurseCheckOldData( currentFolder, timeLimit ) Then 
        Call currentFolder.Delete( True )
    End If 
End Sub

Private Function recurseCheckOldData( ByRef currentFolder, timeLimit )
    ' Until everything is checked, the data is considered newer than timeLimit
    recurseCheckOldData = False

    ' Retrieve a reference to currentFolder if it is not a FSO.Folder
    If TypeName( currentFolder ) <> "Folder" Then 
        With WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            If .FolderExists( currentFolder ) Then 
                Set currentFolder = .GetFolder( currentFolder )
            Else 
                Exit Function
            End If 
        End With
    End If

    ' Check current folder time
    If  currentFolder.DateCreated > timeLimit Then 
        Exit Function
    End If 

    ' Check current folder files
    Dim oFile    
    For Each oFile In currentFolder.Files 
        If oFile.DateCreated > timeLimit Then 
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next 

    ' Recursive call to check each subfolder
    Dim oSubFolder
    For Each oSubFolder In currentFolder.Subfolders
        If Not recurseCheckOldData( oSubFolder, timeLimit ) Then 
            Exit Function
        End If 
    Next 

    ' Up to now everything is older than the indicated time
    recurseCheckOldData = True
End Function
```

Comment: yes! thank you! the first script you wrote is the one i need! But the only problem is that the script removes "temp" if there are no folders or files in it , which i don't want it to do. The "temp" directory should always stay there and never get deleted.Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @E.Karlsson, include an additional argument (ex. `deleteFolder`) to the `removeOldFiles` sub to indicate if the folder must be removed. Pass `False` when calling the sub and `True` in the recursive call from the subfolders loop. Change the last condition to include an `And deleteFolder`. Inner calls will delete the subfolders but initial call will keep it.

Comment: Sorry i'm kind of new to this, i dont really understand where you want me to put it in the code, How do you include an additional argument? Where can i find the last condition?

Comment: @E.Karlsson, first code sample updated with the indicated changes

Comment: ahh, i see what changes you did. Thank you so so much! It is working perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.Subfolders
    Flag = ""   
    If objSubFolder.DateCreated < (Now() - 1) Then
        For Each Thing in objSubFolder
            If thing.DateCreated > Now() - 1 then Flag="yes"
        Next
        If Flag = "yes" then objSubFolder.Delete(True)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I added the script you wrote, but now when i try to run the script on Task Scheduler it only says "The task is currently running. (0x41301)"

Comment: Right click it in TS and choose STOP

Comment: i did that, but it didnt remove the files that should have gotten removed. Maybe i did something wrong in the script, this is how it looks :

Comment: nvm it's to long to put in the comment

Comment: when i try to start the script manually, it says Line: 19 Char: 4 Error: Object doesn't support this property or method, Code: 800A01B6

Comment: i just changed the code in my first comment to how it looks now

Comment: This line? `If Flag = "yes" then objSubFolder.Delete(True)`